# When calling a member function of a class, I get Error C3867

Tags: class, pointers, pointer-to-member

In my displayData member function of the car class, the error says I should create a pointer to the member, do I have to create pointers to the member? If I do how so? I completely forget pointers. Do i make the object a pointer then point to the displayData member function? I get no red squiggles just an error message saying "use '&' to create a pointer to the member. I tried but had no luck.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
class Car
{
private:
int xVal, yVal, zVal;

protected:

public:
Car() { int xVal = 0; int yVal = 0; int zVal = 0; }
Car(int x,int y,int z) { xVal = x; yVal = y; zVal = z; }
~Car() {};
int getX() { return xVal; }
int getY() { return yVal; }
int getZ() { return zVal; }
void changeX(int n) { xVal = n; }
void changeY(int n) { yVal = n; }
void changez(int n) { zVal = n; }
virtual void getData();
void displayData();

};

class Sensor : public Car
{
private:
string sensorType;

protected:

public:
Sensor() { sensorType = "EMPTY"; }
Sensor(int x, int y, int z, string type) :Car(x,y,z) { sensorType = type; }


};

void Car::displayData()
{
cout << "The x values is: " << getX() << endl;
cout << "The y values is: " << getY() << endl;
cout << "The z values is: " << getZ() << endl;
}

int main()
{
Sensor n1;
Sensor n2(20,30,40, "Accelerometer");
n1.displayData;
n2.displayData;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in calling the function.

it should be

```
n1.displayData();
```

instead of

```
n1.displayData;
```

Comment: yeah, didn't mean to delete that, still confused on the polymorphism tho

Comment: Kindly elaborate what thing confuses you in particular